# Prevent view from scrolling and show/hide div on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I am developing a front page of a web application where I want to add on-scroll reveal and hide animation(*But with a catch*).

The user will scroll to my image when the image is in center scrolling of view will stop then one by one div will be visible(*on scroll*), before next, becomes visible last visible div again gets hidden and then after the last div becomes hidden again normal scrolling will start.

All on scroll animation questions on SO are not working for me. This case is a bit different than just normal on scroll animation.

I have just taken scroll position in jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(scroll);
        if (scroll >= 553 && scroll < 1500) {
            $(".invoice-preview-details").addClass("fixedimg");
        } else {
            $(".invoice-preview-details").removeClass("fixedimg");
        }
    });
```

css :

```
.fixedimg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

by the above code, I was able to stop image for some point but when class is removed it's gone(It should be like scrolling up rather disappearing).

I have code to make divs visible and hidden. I am just stuck on the state where scroll detection and preventing the view from scrolling.

comment if you need anything from me.

Comment: Give this a try: https://scrollmagic.io/ or http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/ could help.

Comment: scrollmagic.io is bit confusing and happen to have a lot of issue working with angular. If you have an example that will be great. thanks for the reply.

Comment: did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-scroll-magic ?